# Erro de memory leak nos drivers de conexão quando tento startar o tomcat

Tags: java, postgresql, oracle, tomcat, vraptor

Tenho uma aplicação Java/Vraptor4 em um Tomcat9.0 , quando estou subindo o tomcat o  seguinte erro é lançado:

```html
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.13
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server built:          Nov 2 2018 14:27:55 UTC
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server number:         9.0.13.0
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Name:               Windows 7
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Version:            6.1
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Architecture:          amd64
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Version:           1.8.0_25-b18
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\ambiente_desenvolvimento\workspace\workspace-samu\backend\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\ambiente_desenvolvimento\Apache\apache-tomcat-9.0.13
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:50654
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -javaagent:C:\ambiente_desenvolvimento\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\237\0\.cp\lib\javaagent-shaded.jar
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\ambiente_desenvolvimento\workspace\workspace-samu\backend\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\ambiente_desenvolvimento\Apache\apache-tomcat-9.0.13
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\ambiente_desenvolvimento\workspace\workspace-samu\backend\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\ambiente_desenvolvimento\Apache\apache-tomcat-9.0.13\endorsed
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMAÇÕES: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin;C:\ambiente_desenvolvimento\Apache\maven-3.0.3\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\opscode\chefdk\bin\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ambiente_desenvolvimento\Vagrant\bin;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\isaias.coelho-for\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\isaias.coelho-for\Desktop;;.]
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 1261 ms
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service [Catalina]
abr 09, 2019 10:50:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.13
abr 09, 2019 10:50:15 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
abr 09, 2019 10:50:29 AM org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ProjectStageProducer initProjectStage
INFORMAÇÕES: Computed the following DeltaSpike ProjectStage: Production
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
abr 09, 2019 10:50:35 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
09-abr-2019 10:50:36,784  INFO [EntityManagerFactoryServlet] INICIANDO LEITURA DAS PROPS DO BANCO!
######################################################################################################
#################################     INICIALIZANDO APLICAÇÃO    #####################################
######################################################################################################
VERSÃO DA APLICAÇÃO: 2.2.0
VERSÃO DA BASE DE DADOS: 2.2.1
É PARA ATUALIZAR? : true
######################################################################################################
____________________________________  _______________________
___  __ \__  __ \_  __ \__  __ \_  / / /_  ____/__    |_  __ \
__  /_/ /_  /_/ /  / / /_  / / /  / / /_  /    __  /| |  / / /
_  ____/_  _, _// /_/ /_  /_/ // /_/ / / /___  _  ___ / /_/ /
/_/     /_/ |_| \____/ /_____/ \____/  \____/  /_/  |_\____/

#######################################################################
09-abr-2019 10:50:43,019  INFO [SamuInitializer] CRIANDO AGENDADORES PADRÕES
09-abr-2019 10:50:43,019  INFO [SamuInitializer] AGENDADORES PADRÕES CRIADOS
######################################################################################################
###############################     SERVIDOR ATUALIZADO     ##########################################
######################################################################################################
VERSÃO DA APLICAÇÃO: 2.2.0
VERSÃO DA BASE DE DADOS: 2.2.1
######################################################################################################
######################################################################################################
abr 09, 2019 10:50:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
GRAVE: Exception starting filter [vraptor]
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 19896
 at com.thoughtworks.paranamer.BytecodeReadingParanamer$ClassReader.readUnsignedShort(BytecodeReadingParanamer.java:722)
 at com.thoughtworks.paranamer.BytecodeReadingParanamer$ClassReader.accept(BytecodeReadingParanamer.java:563)
 at com.thoughtworks.paranamer.BytecodeReadingParanamer$ClassReader.access$200(BytecodeReadingParanamer.java:338)
 at com.thoughtworks.paranamer.BytecodeReadingParanamer.lookupParameterNames(BytecodeReadingParanamer.java:103)
 at com.thoughtworks.paranamer.AnnotationParanamer.lookupParameterNames(AnnotationParanamer.java:110)
 at com.thoughtworks.paranamer.CachingParanamer.lookupParameterNames(CachingParanamer.java:90)
 at com.thoughtworks.paranamer.CachingParanamer.lookupParameterNames(CachingParanamer.java:83)
 at br.com.caelum.vraptor.http.ParanamerNameProvider.parametersFor(ParanamerNameProvider.java:50)
 at br.com.caelum.vraptor.http.ParanamerNameProvider$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.parametersFor(Unknown Source)
 at br.com.caelum.vraptor.http.route.DefaultTypeFinder.getParameterTypes(DefaultTypeFinder.java:57)
 at br.com.caelum.vraptor.http.route.DefaultTypeFinder$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getParameterTypes(Unknown Source)
 at br.com.caelum.vraptor.http.route.DefaultRouteBuilder.addParametersInfo(DefaultRouteBuilder.java:196)
 at br.com.caelum.vraptor.http.route.DefaultRouteBuilder.is(DefaultRouteBuilder.java:185)
 at br.com.caelum.vraptor.http.route.PathAnnotationRoutesParser.registerRulesFor(PathAnnotationRoutesParser.java:117)
 at br.com.caelum.vraptor.http.route.PathAnnotationRoutesParser.rulesFor(PathAnnotationRoutesParser.java:91)
 at br.com.caelum.vraptor.http.route.PathAnnotationRoutesParser$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.rulesFor(Unknown Source)
 at br.com.caelum.vraptor.ioc.ControllerHandler.handle(ControllerHandler.java:66)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
 at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:78)
 at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:129)
 at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:299)
 at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:277)
 at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:255)
 at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:269)
 at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:258)
 at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154)
 at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:136)
 at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:717)
 at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.fireEvent(ForwardingBeanManager.java:101)
 at br.com.caelum.vraptor.ioc.cdi.StereotypesRegistry.configure(StereotypesRegistry.java:54)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
 at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:78)
 at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:129)
 at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:299)
 at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:277)
 at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:255)
 at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:269)
 at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:258)
 at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:92)
 at br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.init(VRaptor.java:94)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:270)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:251)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4491)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1432)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1422)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
 at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1432)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1422)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
 at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:801)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:695)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)

abr 09, 2019 10:50:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
abr 09, 2019 10:50:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Context [/samu-server] startup failed due to previous errors
EMF DESTRUIDO
abr 09, 2019 10:50:44 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
ADVERTÊNCIA: The web application [samu-server] registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
abr 09, 2019 10:50:44 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
ADVERTÊNCIA: The web application [samu-server] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
abr 09, 2019 10:50:44 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
abr 09, 2019 10:50:44 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
abr 09, 2019 10:50:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAÇÕES: Server startup in 31216 ms
```

A aplicação sobe, porém nenhuma comunicação com o banco de dados é alcançada.
Uso libs dos drivers em tomcat/libs 
postgresql-9.4-1201-jdbc41
ojdbc7-ojdbc7

```
<!-- POSTGRES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ORACLE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ojdbc7</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>ojdbc7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Descrobri que essa é a classe que faz quebrar durante o start, mas não consigo identificar a causa, alguém pode ajudar?

```java
package br.com.consulfarmasaude.api.sigss.paciente;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

import br.com.caelum.vraptor.Consumes;
import br.com.caelum.vraptor.Controller;
import br.com.caelum.vraptor.Get;
import br.com.caelum.vraptor.Path;
import br.com.consulfarmasaude.samu.core.CoreController;
import br.com.consulfarmasaude.samu.core.CoreUtils;
import br.com.consulfarmasaude.samu.core.exception.CoreMessageException;
import br.com.consulfarmasaude.samu.core.filtro.CoreFiltroSearch;
import br.com.consulfarmasaude.samu.core.filtro.ICoreFiltro;
import br.com.consulfarmasaude.samu.core.permissao.acesso.Acesso;

@Controller
@Path("/paciente-api")
@Acesso(value = "Paciente API")
public class PacienteAPIController extends CoreController {

    @Inject
    private IPacienteAPIBeanLocal pacienteAPIBean;

//  @Get("/")
//  public void buscarPacienteAPIPorNome(String nome) {
//      List<PacienteAPI> busca = pacienteAPIBean.buscarPacienteAPIPorNome(nome);
//      resultAsJson().from(busca).serialize();
//  }

    @Get("/")
    @Consumes(CoreUtils.APPJSON)
    public void buscarPacienteAPIPorFiltro() {
        CoreFiltroSearch filtros = getFiltros();
        validarBusca(filtros);
        List<PacienteAPI> busca = pacienteAPIBean.buscarPacienteAPIPorFiltro(montarQueryString(filtros));
        resultAsJson().from(busca).serialize();
    }

    private void validarBusca(CoreFiltroSearch filtros) {
        String nome = filtros.splitValueFromList("nome");
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(nome) || (StringUtils.isNotBlank(nome) && filtros.getFiltros().size() == 1)) {
            throw new CoreMessageException(null, null);
        }
    }

    private String montarQueryString(CoreFiltroSearch filter) {
        return filter.getFiltros().stream().map(p -> urlEncodeUTF8(p.getChave()) + "=" + urlEncodeUTF8(p.getValor()))
                .reduce((p1, p2) -> p1 + "&" + p2).orElse("");
    }

    static String urlEncodeUTF8(Map<?, ?> map) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append("&");
            }
            sb.append(String.format("%s=%s", urlEncodeUTF8(entry.getKey().toString()),
                    urlEncodeUTF8(entry.getValue().toString())));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    static String urlEncodeUTF8(String s) {
        try {
            return URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(e);
        }
    }

    private PacienteAPI montarFiltro(CoreFiltroSearch filter) {
        PacienteAPI pacienteApi = new PacienteAPI();
        for (ICoreFiltro filtro : filter.getFiltros()) {
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(filtro.getChave())) {
                String chave = filtro.getChave();
                switch (chave) {
                case "nome":
                    pacienteApi.setNome(filtro.getValor());
                    break;
                case "dataNascimento":
                    pacienteApi.setDataNasc(filtro.getValor());
                    break;
                case "nomeMae":
                    pacienteApi.setNomeMae(filtro.getValor());
                    break;
                case "cns":
                    pacienteApi.setCartaoSus(filtro.getValor());
                    break;
                case "sexo":
                    pacienteApi.setSexo(filtro.getValor());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return pacienteApi;
    }

    @Get("/prontuario/")
    @Consumes(CoreUtils.APPJSON)
    public void buscarLinkProntuarioPaciente(PacienteAPI paciente) {
        String link = pacienteAPIBean.buscarProntuarioPaciente(paciente);
        resultAsJson().from(link).serialize();
    }

}
```

Comment: As configurações de conexão com o banco estão corretas? Dê uma verificada.

Comment: estão, consigo conectar com o banco em uma branch mais antiga, eu descobri que é em uma determinada classe que quebra, tem como eu postar a classe ?