# Gerar String a partir de conteúdo da lista

Tags: java, lógica, java-8

Tenho uma classe chamada `CoreFiltroSearch` que tem uma lista de `ICoreFiltro` chamada `filtros`. Segue a classe e a interface:

```
public class CoreFiltroSearch {

    private List<ICoreFiltro> filtros = new ArrayList<>();
    private String            order   = "asc";
    private String            sort    = "id";
    private Integer           page    = 0;
    private Integer           size    = 40;
}

public interface ICoreFiltro {

    String getChave();

    String getValor();

    Boolean isQFilter();

    Boolean isDateFilter();

}
```

A partir da lista `filtros`, preciso criar uma `String` usando os campos `getChave()` e `getvalor()` que são do elemento `ICoreFiltro`.

Eu tentei fazer usando uma solução que encontrei em um blog, porém não consigo sequer subir o servidor usando essa solução,  [coloquei a pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/374521/erro-de-memory-leak-nos-drivers-de-conex%C3%A3o-quando-tento-startar-o-tomcat), a solução que usei na tentativa de conseguir criar essa `String` foi essa:

```
private String montarQueryString(CoreFiltroSearch filter) {
    return filter.getFiltros().stream()
            .map(p -> urlEncodeUTF8(p.getChave()) + "=" + urlEncodeUTF8(p.getValor()))
            .reduce((p1, p2) -> p1 + "&" + p2)
            .map(s -> "?" + s).orElse("");
}

static String urlEncodeUTF8(String s) {
    try {
        return URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(e);
    }
}
```

Se alguém poder me ajudar com uma solução melhor eu agradeço, mas acho que não existe problema nessa lógica.

Comment: Eu fiz isso semana passada, mas sem "reduzir". Apenas mapeei e coletei no final. Vou passar o link do projeto depois explico numa resposta

Comment: https://gitlab.com/geosales-open-source/tc-http-conn/blob/master/src/main/java/br/com/softsite/httpconn/HttpConn.java no método `serializeFormContent`. Estou tendo dificuldades de mandar o link da linha exata por conta do navegador do smartphone não ajudar, mas é nesse método que faço a magia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passamos por uma situação semelhante. Como gerar a string de `queryParam` a partir de um conjunto de parametrizações? Mais especificamente, a partir de um conjunto de chaves e valores?

Como mencionei no comentário, passei por essa necessidade [em um projeto](https://gitlab.com/geosales-open-source/tc-http-conn/blob/master/src/main/java/br/com/softsite/httpconn/HttpConn.java) aberto da empresa.

A ideia de começar de uma lista de chave/valor tivemos bem parecidas, então é um bom começo. Assumi no meu projeto que possam existir parâmetros de `query` que sejam simplesmente indicados pela presença, então tratei a possibilidade do "valor" associado à "chave" ser nulo. Mas não parece ser esse o seu caso. Vou assumir que sempre são preenchidos.

Então, mapeamos essa *stream* de chave/valor em uma *stream* de strings. Até aí concordamos perfeitamente:

```
filter.getFiltros().stream()
    .map(p -> urlEncodeUTF8(p.getChave()) + "=" + urlEncodeUTF8(p.getValor()))
```

Depois disso, precisamos agora transformar isso em uma grande string. Como eu tive de conhecer grande parte da biblioteca de *stream* do Java 8 para [dar suporte no TotalCross](https://gitlab.com/geosales-open-source/totalcross-functional-toolbox) a algo suficientemente semelhante, já imaginei isso como sendo uma coleção usando o coletor `joining`.

Existem 3 variações do `joining`:

1. a que não recebe argumentos, a saída são as strings uma do lado da outrasemnadanomeio
2. a que recebe um argumento, que delimita o-separador-entre-as-strings-da-stream
3. a que recebe 3 argumentos, semelhante a variação anterior, porém adicionando uma sequência de carácteres no começo e outra no final

Como não desejamos alterar nada nem no começo, nem no final, mas alternar esses pares de chave/valor com "`&`", então devemos usar o `collect(Collectors.joining("&"))`. Ficando assim o código:

```
filter.getFiltros().stream()
    .map(p -> urlEncodeUTF8(p.getChave()) + "=" + urlEncodeUTF8(p.getValor()))
    .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
```

---

Se quiser se aprofundar um pouco mais nas questões de reduzir/coletar, lembro dessas duas questões aqui no SOpt que tratam disso:

- [Em um map/reduce no Java, a operação de acumulação deve gerar um novo objeto? Ou posso aproveitar o antigo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/316014/64969)
- [Como utilizar Stream.reduce() de forma apropriada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/305049/64969)